# How to change a certain value in a column of a list into NA in R?

Tags: r, list, rename, cell, na

I would like to change -1 value of my V3 column into NA, but don't know how...

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(94756)

mat1 <- matrix(sample(seq(-1,100, 0.11),50,replace = TRUE),ncol = 5)  
mat1 <- as.data.frame(mat1)
mat1[8,3] <- -1
mat1[1,3] <- -1
mat1[5,3] <- -1

mat2 <- matrix(sample(seq(-1,100, 0.11),50, replace = TRUE),ncol = 5)  
mat2 <- as.data.frame(mat2)
mat2[8,3] <- -1
mat2[1,3] <- -1
mat2[5,3] <- -1

mat3 <- matrix(sample(seq(-1,100, 0.11), 50,replace = TRUE),ncol = 5)  
mat3 <- as.data.frame(mat2)
mat3[2,3] <- -1
mat3[4,3] <- -1
mat3[8,3] <- -1

data <- list(mat1, mat2, mat3)
```

Can anyone help please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
lapply(data, function(d) {d$V3[d$V3 == -1]  <- "NA"; d})
```

Comment: I would like to change it in every mat (1,2 and 3) with one single code.

Comment: and they're all part of a list

Comment: @timtams I changed the code for a list problem.

Comment: Another question: how could I delete it instead?